# Getting positions without clicking on plot with ginput command on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, mousemove, ginput

I am trying to get positions at the following map with ginput command. But the problem is I want to see the position of the point before clicking it.

Is it possible to that? 
After I clicked N points I can see positions, but I can not click them anymore.  I should see the position first and after that I need to click it.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
clc
clear
close all
geoaxes('Units','normalized');
N=5;
set (gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseMove);

for i=1:N

[lat,lon]=ginput(1)
hold on
geolimits('manual')
geoscatter(lat,lon,'filled','b')
end

set (gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseMove);

function mouseMove (object, eventdata)
C = get (gcf, 'CurrentPoint');
title(gca, ['(X,Y) = (', num2str(C(1,1)), ', ',num2str(C(1,2)), ')']);
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by “see the positions before clicking”? Maybe you mean that you want to see the current coordinates of the mouse cursor?

Comment: I want to see the positions of the points when I am scrolling mouse on the map. If you run this code it actually work after I select 5 points. But I want to see the coordinates of the points then I want to click.  I mean, first I need to find the correct point while I am scrolling mouse, lets say I found [89 , 520] then I will click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the mapping toolbox you can use `gcpmap` to simplify this I think.

The main issue just requires a `drawnow` in the callback function. Then I used `waitforbuttonpress` and `CurrentPoint` to get the location of the click instead of `ginput`.

```
h = geoaxes('Units','normalized');
geolimits('manual')
set (gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(x,y) mouseMove(x,y,h));
hold on

N=5;
for i=1:N
    waitforbuttonpress;
    pt = h.CurrentPoint;
    lat = pt(1,1);
    lon = pt(1,2);
    geoscatter(lat,lon,'filled','b')
end
hold off


function mouseMove (~, ~, handle)
C = handle.CurrentPoint;
title(gca, ['(X,Y) = (', num2str(C(1,1)), ', ',num2str(C(1,2)), ')']);
drawnow
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem your having is that the `ginput` function temporarily overrides some callbacks, one way to solve this is to use a `listener` to listen for the mouse press on the axes instead,

```
function myFunction
    % create a figure and an axes
    f = figure;
    ax = axes( 'parent', f );

    % give the axes a title
    t = title ( ax, '');
    % add a callback to update the title when the mouse is moving
    f.WindowButtonMotionFcn = @(a,b)updateTitle ( ax, t );
    % add a listener to the user clicking on the mouse
    addlistener ( ax, 'Hit', @(a,b)mousePress ( ax, t ) )
end
function updateTitle ( ax, t, str )
  % this function updates the title
  % 2 input args is from the mouse moving, the 3rd is only passed in
  %   when the mouoe button is pressed
  if nargin == 2; str = ''; end
  % get the current point of the axes
  cp  = ax.CurrentPoint(1,1:2);
  % check to see if its in the axes limits
  if cp(1) > ax.XLim(1) && cp(1) < ax.XLim(2) && ...
      cp(2) > ax.YLim(1) && cp(2) < ax.YLim(2)
    % update the string
    t.String = sprintf ( '%f,%f %s', cp, str );
  else
    % if ourside the limits tell the user
    t.String = 'Outside Axes';
  end
end
% this function is run when the mouse is pressed
function mousePress ( ax, t )
  updateTitle ( ax, t, '- Button Pressed' );
end
```

This will require some refactoring of your code, but its a powerful method and introduces you to listeners.

Image when the mouse is moving:

[image: Image when the mouse is moving]

Image when the mouse is pressed:
[image: Image when the mouse is pressed]